# How to get ion-slide index on click?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to get slide index on click, I have ion-slides and its options are per page 2.5 slide. When I try to get active index it getting zero(0).

> here my code

```
@ViewChild(IonSlides, { static: false }) slides: IonSlides;
slideOpts = {
  slidesPerView: 2.5,
  zoom: false,
  slideShadows: true
};

getIndex() {
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index) => {
      this.currentIndex = index;
      console.log(this.currentIndex);
    })
}
```

> here my HTML

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" #slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let i=index` to get index id. You can get an index like this:

```
slideOpts = {
    slidesPerView: 2.5,
    zoom: false,
    slideShadows: true
  };

  items = [
    {
      name: 'test1'
    },
    {
      name: 'test1'
    },
    {
      name: 'test1'
    },
    {
      name: 'test1'
    }
  ]

getSlideIndex(i: number) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

> in Html

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-button (click)="getSlideIndex(i)">
          {{item.name}}
        </ion-button>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

hope it helps you :)

Comment: But how about when I want to get selected slide index when I click button outside of ion-slides?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it logs slide index for me.

In HTML

```
<ion-slides pager="true" #mySlider (ionSlidesDidLoad)="slidesDidLoad(mySlider)"
    (ionSlideTransitionEnd)="slideChanged(mySlider)">
<ion-slide (click)="getSlideIndex()"> ... </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

On your ts file

```
@ViewChild('mySlider', { static: true }) slider: IonSlides;

slidesDidLoad(slides: IonSlides) {
    slides.startAutoplay();
    slides.getActiveIndex().then(index => {
      console.log(index);
    });
  }

  slideChanged(slides: IonSlides) {
    slides.startAutoplay();
    slides.getActiveIndex().then(index => {
      console.log(index);
    });
  }

getSlideIndex(){ //updated
this.slider.getActiveIndex().then(index => {
      console.log(index);
    });
}
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want index on click.

Comment: On click of a particular slide?

Comment: @user9088454, Did you check?

Comment: I added options in my code, It's treating entire slide as one so, for first 2.5 slides index is coming out to be `0`. If i change slide index changes to `1`

Comment: Better way could be displaying `1` slide per view if it serves your requirement.